# Chrome extension notification in mobile

Tags: google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to show the notification from extension in mobile device via chrome browser?

This is not clear in google developer document.

Comment: No, it is not possible on its own just using chrome APIs. You'd need another service like Firebase, and an app installed in the mobile device.

Comment: Thanks Ivan for the answer